# Why browser is blocking when jquery load large amounts of data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I noticed a problem in many places and on my site, and I'm interested about solution.

Why any browser is blocking when jquery load large amounts of data?

On one site I made statistics that check over 11,000 entries what made pagination and show lists of 400 entries from the database. When I start to load that data, any function on my browser stop to work until the load is complete. The same also happens when I'm working in phpMyAdmin.

Is there a way to improve the load, or to prevent the blocking of? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
This is jQuery what I use:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="loading.gif" /> Loading...</div>').load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':0}, function() {$("#1-page").addClass('active');});  //initial page number to load

    $(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {
        var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
        var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); //clicked_id[0] holds the page number we need
        $('#if').removeClass('active'); //remove any active class
        $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="loading.gif" /> Loading...</div>').load("fetch_pages.php", {'page': (page_num-1)}, function(){});
        $(this).addClass('active'); //add active class to currently clicked element
        return false; //prevent going to herf link
    });
});
</script>
```

On fetch_pages.php is a simple PHP loop with while function.

Comment: Are you sure that you're loading the data asynchronously?

Comment: How do you make the ajax call? With `settings` property `async: false`?

Comment: Can you post the code used to load the data?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I did not understand the question. I take the data with PHP using a loop in jQuery and use .load() function to display that data in page

Comment: @levi I edited my question, that's my code.

Comment: @SvenSchürmann with jQuery.load() function

Comment: After tuning your javascript you could optimise your php. I think that will be an another bottle neck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to solve your problem : 
Send request with $.ajax along with async true

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getPage(pageno)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "fetch_pages.php",
            data: "page="+pageno,
            async: true,
            crossDomain: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                 $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="loading.gif" /> Loading...</div>')
            },
            success: function (resp){
                $("#results").html(resp);
                $("#"+pageno+"-page").addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
    //initial page number to load
    getPage(0);

    $(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {
        var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
        var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); //clicked_id[0] holds the page number we need
        $('#if').removeClass('active'); //remove any active class
        getPage(page_num-1);
        return false; //prevent going to herf link
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, this is great function but result is same. I still have same problem with load but load is now faster arround 1s. Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure any other script is not blocking the page ? or you need to provide URL or demo URL of your page so i can check :)